# Add class again only if it previously existed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a class "fixed" to the html tag, but only on some pages on my website (where I want to add position: fixed to block the scroll). When I open the hamburger menu, I want that class removed so the user can scroll through the navigation. I did it this way:

```js
elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
    elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi', 'is-active');
    if ($('html').hasClass('fixed')) {
      $('html').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  } else {
    elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi', 'is-active');
    // how to add it back here?
  }
  
});
```

When I close the hamburger menu, I want to add the class back, but only to the pages that previously had it, not to all of them. How to do that?

Comment: did you tried toggleClass();  ??

Comment: That way, I add the class fixed to other elements as well. Lol

Comment: you can add an extra class to html or body elements like "html-fixed-menu" in the pages that you had the "fixed" class in and based on  this class you can toggle the fixed class  like  $('html.html-fixed').removeClass('fixed'); and $('html.html-fixed').addClass('fixed');

Comment: can you provide your html so i can help you to solve your problem

Comment: @MoneerKamal Got it, great idea. I'll try to do that.

Comment: To implement the same @MoneerKamal 's idea, I'd use a custom `data-` attribute instead of a class.

Comment: @PA. Thank you, I used your solution! `if (document.documentElement.hasAttribute('data-fixed')) { document.documentElement.classList.remove('fixed'); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe like this:

```
elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
    elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi', 'is-active');
    if ($('html').hasClass('fixed')) {
       $('html').removeClass('fixed');
       $('html').addClass('tmp-fixed');//add temp class
    }
  } else {
    elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi', 'is-active');
    if ($('html').hasClass('tmp-fixed')) { 
       $('html').addClass('fixed');
       $('html').removeClass('tmp-fixed');
    }
  }
  
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just have changed a temporary class to data- attribute.